# In case of nested iFrames how does x-Frame-option work?

Tags: iframe, http-headers, x-frame-options, clickjacking

I have a web page that renders some nested iFrames. Lets say abc.com loads def.com, that in-turn opens ghi.com in another iFrame. abc.com -> def.com -> ghi.com

ghi.com has option set to only allow some specific sites to iFrame it. What should be the setting in ghi.com to allow it to be rendered? Do we need to white list both abc.com and def.com, or only def.com, or abc.com?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this situation with X-Frame-Options when trying to allow this scenario in IE 11.  I found that putting an X-Frame-Options value of "ALLOW-FROM top-level-site-domain" worked for the response in both of the nested iFrames.  Using your example, both def.com and ghi.com response would set headers similar to:

"X-Frame-Options": ALLOW-FROM abc.com

As a side note, according to [OWasp](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet#X-Frame-Options_Header_Types), setting the X-Frame-Options header to ALLOW-FROM for def.com and SAMEORIGIN for ghi.com in your example will not work.

Remember that other browsers such as Chrome support Content-Security-Policy which you'll also want to set.  In our case our domains were all subdomains so our scenario worked out easily with this header using wildcards.  A scenario of first.example.com -> second.example.com -> third.example.com allowed us to set the following for second and third.example.com response header:

"Content-Security-Policy": frame-ancestors 'self' https://*.example.com